# Failed to apply Eslint fixes to the document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy teniendo un problema con eslint bastante confusa, ya que en ciertos archivos me deja aplicar el Fix de corrección de código y en otro me tira el error de que no puedo, como si algo se hubiera corrompido.

Les dejo mi configuración de `.eslintrc.js`

```js
module.exports = {
    'env': {
        'browser': true,
        'es6': true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "node": true
    },
    'extends': [
        'airbnb/base',
        'react-app',
    ],
    "settings": {
            "import/resolver": {
                "node": {
                    "extensions": [".js",".jsx"],
                    "moduleDirectory": ['node_modules', 'src/'],
                }
            }
    },
    'globals': {
        'Atomics': 'readonly',
        'SharedArrayBuffer': 'readonly'
    },
    'parserOptions': {
        'ecmaFeatures': {
            'jsx': true
        },
        'ecmaVersion': 2018,
        'sourceType': 'module'
    },
    'plugins': [
        'react'
    ]
}
```

En consola me tira este error:

```
[Info  - 13:28:59] Cannot read property 'range' of null Occurred while linting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuve ese problema con ciertos archivos solamente, no identifique la raíz del problema como tal, sin embargo agregando estas lineas ayudo a que todas las demás reglas funcionaran correctamente evitando ese error, que por lo que veo es de indentacion.

> eslintrc.js

```
"rules": {
  "no-nested-ternary": "off",
  "template-curly-spacing" : "off",
  "indent" : 0,
}
```